# How to store multiple objects in dictionary?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I am a newbie in javascript and i have the following `input` that i would like to `output` to the following structure below. I'm trying to store as a `JSON` format so I can retrieve it later. But I'm not quite sure how to do it. Can someone explain or assist me with this? Thanks in advance!

**Input**

```
Andy
19
M
Susan
28
F
Mark
32
M
```

**Output**

```
{
    { 
            name: "Andy", 
            age: "19", 
            gender: "M" 
    },
    { 
            name: "Susann", 
            age: "28", 
            gender: "F" 
    },
    { 
            name: "Mark", 
            age: "32", 
            gender: "M" 
    },
}
```

Comment: This output you want is not valid in javascript. You can read about [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to understand it better.

Comment: Why not use a list instead? Otherwise, you can give the objects unique keys, IDK what they may be in your subject area.

Comment: An alternative would be using an Array of Objects.

Comment: I suspect you meant to use an array so the outermost `{` & `}` should have been `[` & `]`

Comment: @lucas - Ah i see. I've been searching for answers but to no avail. Thanks for the info (:

Answer (score 0):

Storing as an array should do it.

```
const data = [
    { 
            name: "Andy", 
            age: "19", 
            gender: "M" 
    },
    { 
            name: "Susann", 
            age: "28", 
            gender: "F" 
    },
    { 
            name: "Mark", 
            age: "32", 
            gender: "M" 
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks for the response! But how do i dynamically append to the array? @BennyLava

Comment: how about this - `data.push({name: 'corezel789', age: 21, gender: 'M'})`

Answer (score 0):

Say your input was a string with line breaks as the delimiter, and your output you wanted an array of objects, you could do it like this:

```js
var input = "Andy\r\n" +
"19\r\n" +
"M\r\n" +
"Susan\r\n" +
"28\r\n" +
"F\r\n" +
"Mark\r\n" +
"32\r\n" +
"M";

var arr = input.split("\r\n");
var output = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i+=3){
    output.push({
      name: arr[i],
      age:arr[i+1],
      gender:arr[i+2]
    });
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, But is this the best way do store the objects?

Comment: @scorezel789 "best" is somewhat subjective, and depends on what you're trying to do. This isnt really storing anything, its changing one format to another, which is what I thought you were asking.